# Contexto Delimitado e Módulos/Pacotes

Tags: ddd

Conforme o Domain Driven Design:

- Os pactoes devem contar uma história, fazem parte da linguagem onipresente, organizam conceitos relacionados;
- O contexto delimitado é a delimitação onde os termos da linguagem onipresente têm significado;

Dúvidas:

- O contexto delimitado deve ser implementado como um pacote/namespace?
- Se o contexto delimitado for um pacote/namespace, os pacotes que contam a história do software devem estar dentro do contexto delimitado?

**como deve ser declarado o pacote/namespace?**

*Nome_do_contexto_delimitado \ Nome_do_pacote*

ou

*Nome_do_pacote \ Nome_do_contexto_delimitado*

Answer (score 2):

Vários *packages* ("pacotes") podem compor juntos um único *bounded context* ("contexto delimitado"), não existe necessariamente relação de 1 pra 1.

Uma estrutura de nome de *package* que funciona bem é:

```
contexto.assunto
```

Onde o nome do *bounded context* é a raiz ou está próximo da raiz do *package* (a raiz também pode ser algo como *com.nomeempresa*, daí a estrutura do nome do package seria *com.nomeempresa.contexto.assunto*)

"Assunto" aqui é uma área de interesse dentro daquele contexto.

Exemplos de nomes de packages e classes:

***Bounded context* Vendas:**

```
marketing.cliente.Cliente
marketing.cliente.Categoria
marketing.produto.Produto
marketing.produto.Categoria
```

***Bounded context* Logística:**

```
logistica.cliente.Cliente
logistica.produto.Produto
```

**O assunto pode ter subdivisões. Por exemplo:**

```
marketing.produto.review.Review
marketing.produto.review.Consumidor
marketing.produto.review.Editor
```

#### Identificação da camada no nome do package

Também pode haver na raiz ou próximo à raiz do nome do *package* a indicação da camada lógica daquele código, assim:

```
business.contexto.assunto
application.contexto.assunto
```

Isso ajuda a manter o respeito nas relações entre as camadas (um código de *business* jamais deve referenciar um código de *application*).

Há quem faça esta separação usando pastas ou diretórios no projeto. Informar a camada no nome do próprio package, entretanto, permite identificar, analisando apenas o código fonte, que alguma referência está desrespeitando o relacionamento entre as camadas. Por exemplo (Java):

```
package business.marketing;

import application.marketing.produto.*;

public class Cliente {...
```

No código acima, a referência que desrespeita as relações está evidente (e pode ser detectada com uma analisadorde código) de uma maneira que não estaria se a camada não estivesse identificada no nome do *package*.